# question about the closure of subset

Tags: general-topology

‎A ‎subset ‎$‎‎A‎$  ‎of ‎‎space ‎$  ‎(‎‎X‎,\tau)$ ‎has ‎‎$‎\beta‎‎$‎-‎property‎ ‎if  ‎every‎ ‎$‎\tau‎$‎-open cover of ‎‎$‎A‎$‎ has a finite subfamily whose ‎‎$‎\tau‎$‎‎-closures cover ‎‎$‎int ‎‎A‎$‎.‎‎‎

> A‎uppose ‎the ‎subset  ‎$ A‎ ‎‎\subseteq ‎X‎ $‎‎has ‎the ‎$‎\beta‎‎$‎-‎property‎‎‎, ‎does‎ the closure of‎$‎A‎$ ‎have‎$‎\beta‎‎$‎-‎property?‎

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual topology, and let $A=\Bbb Q$. $A$ trivially has the $\beta$-property, since its interior is empty, but $\operatorname{cl}A=\Bbb R$ does not.